# Where to place making/adding new Entity, should it go in a new ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a View with a form which displays data from objects that are in an `ObservableCollection` that is in a ViewModel. The `ObservableCollection` lets me page through the data.

The objects in the `ObservableCollection` are of type `ItemTypeViewModel`. This is a wrapper class that wraps the entity `ItemType`. `ItemType` itself comes from Linq2SQL (there are no domain classes, the basis of the app was already built)).

Now, I need to be able to create new ItemTypes. I want to use the form to do that. I have a `New` button, which will kick off a command in the ViewModel of the View, which delegates it to a method in the same ViewModel (probably something like `CreateNewItemType()`. This method will need to create a new `ItemType`, but here is where my dilemma is. Most examples I see use the Domain class to create a new instance, e.g.

`Customer customer = Customer.CreateNewCustomer();`

But since I don't have any domain classes, I can't do this. It feels weird putting it in the ViewModel of the View, as well as putting it in the ViewModel that wraps the `ItemType`
entity.

What is a good approach to take here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be way off base here, but it sounds like you have a Controller that is serving up an `ObservableCollection<ItemType>`.

It also sounds like on the same page (or a similar page) you want to be able to accept user input via form elements and have those elements collectively be used to populate a new instance of `ItemType`.

If this is the case, the post action of your form should be submitting to a Controller and the controller should be able to access as incoming parameters either individual form elements cast as their appropriate data types, or if you are using strongly-typed views, you should be able to cast all of the form parameters directly back to an instance of `ItemType` implicitly merely by changing the signature of your controller method to accept a parameter of type `ItemType`.

This is all, of course, assuming you are working within the Asp.Net MVC framework, no?

Comment: Ahh, if that is the case, I would look into using Prism from the Patterns and Practices team.  Here is a link : http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/.  Additionally, Brian Noyes, a MVP and Regional Director has worked with that team on the Prism project and would be an excellent resource to reach out to.

Comment: Yes, it's MVVM and WPF. I will def. read up on Prism, but the problem is that it's all out of my hands (Prism wise) since I'm only the guy that get's to work on a module.

Comment: I understand your situation, to me it seems your only option is to access the classes defined in the Linq2Sql model from within the ViewModel for your view.  The ViewModel would need access to both the Linq2Sql ObjectContext and the strongly-typed objects associated with your model in order to create and save your user information using the Linq2Sql Data Layer...because Linq2Sql tends to combine BusinessLogic and Data Access, you could potentially create an extension method directly off your type (Model) and pass it the form values directly, which would add your typed item to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reply, but I'm not quite sure if it is the way:
I will subscrobe myself in the viewmodel the collection changed event. When user add new item or delete one I will collect addition/removal in two separate collection. Then, in the commit phase, I will crete new ItemType instance from the data in the new items collection and submit these records to DB, as well as performing the deletes. Worst if you need to perform check on *modifications* to single rows...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already mapped out how I want to tackle this (adding/removing), but I don't know where to put the creation and returning of the new (empty) ItemType.